# MongoDB Error: user is not allowed to do action [serverStatus] on [admin.]

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, database-backups

My project is using NestJS. I got this error when I tried to write a backup file from my database.

```
VError: pack collection: 'collection name' failed:   
  user is not allowed to do action [serverStatus] on [admin.]
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-snapshot/src/connectors/filesystem/FileSystemDuplexConnector.ts:45:40)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-snapshot/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/catchError.ts:132:23)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-snapshot/src/connectors/filesystem/FileSystemDuplexConnector.ts:267:26
    at Sink.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tar-stream/pack.js:175:14)
    at Sink.f (/usr/src/app/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at Sink.onfinish (/usr/src/app/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:31:27)  
...  
MongoURI: mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster/databaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin
```

Comment: Please check the roles for your username?

Comment: Thanks you very match, i change role to atlasAdmin and it work